# How to specify data inside of predefined interface?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to add **data in props** to child components. Sadly typescript keep screaming on me.

> TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type '{}'.

Props.match.params ( props sent by router ) don't have any data specified in them so I know why ts is screaming.

Thats my code:

```
import React from "react"
import {RouteComponentProps} from "react-router";

export const Treads: React.FC<RouteComponentProps> = (props) => {
    return <div>
        Tag from url: {props.match.params.name}
    </div>
}
```

I am still new to typescript."RouteComponentProps" has its own interface inside of react files ( which I prefer not to touch ). How can I set type of data inside of props? **This component will always only get "name"**

I know I can force "props: any" but I can use pure JS for that.

I tried using extend:

```
interface newProps extends PropsWithChildren<RouteComponentProps>{
    params: Params;
    isExact: boolean;
    path: string;
    url: string;
}
```

but params are dynamically added so I have no idea what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [definition of `RouteComponentProps`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/d1a3e67d65e6945def44e3093e995c130050a6d9/types/react-router/index.d.ts#L69-L78) accepts a generic parameter. You can use e.g. `React.FC<RouteComponentProps<{ name: string}>>` to make `params` have a `name: string` property. You can also replace `{ name: string }` with the name of a type/interface for readability, of course.

Comment: Oh. I had no idea that you can provide props that way. Big +1 from me <3